# cocos2d sprite frame cache unable to change

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

in my game i want to make several themes. (like doodle jump)
the frame names are the same in different themes and i think i just need to change the plist files.

in the Helper.m:

```
+(void) addCache {

ThemeTypes themeType = [Helper getCurrentThemeType];

if (themeType == ThemeTypeDefaultTheme) {
    [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"block.plist"];
}
else if (themeType == ThemeTypeJungleTheme) {
    [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"jungle1.plist"];
    [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"jungle2.plist"];
}
else if (themeType == ThemeTypeXmasTheme) {
    [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"xmas1.plist"];
    [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"xmas2.plist"];
}
else if (themeType == ThemeTypeWhiteTheme) {
    [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"blockwhite.plist"];
}
else if (themeType == ThemeTypeOuterSpaceTheme) {
    [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"outer1.plist"];
}
else if (themeType == ThemeTypeSkyTheme) {
    [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"sky1.plist"];
    [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"sky2.plist"];
}
else {

}
}


+(void) purgeCache {
    [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] removeSpriteFrames];
    [CCSpriteFrameCache purgeSharedSpriteFrameCache];
}

+(void) refreshCache {
    [Helper purgeCache];
    [Helper addCache];
}
```

in appdelegate, i will call 'addcache', then in my ShopScene, when choosing a theme, 'refresh cache' will get called.

this code is in my BlockCache ('normal block' is a kind of block in game')

```
    CCSpriteFrame* frame = [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:@"normal.png"];
    batch = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithTexture:frame.texture];
    [self addChild:batch];
```

(note that @"normal.png" exist in every plist files. use the same name.

but after changing the theme, the 'block cache' still use the original images. however, the background etc uses the correct one (I use bg = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName: ] method

UPDATE: after choosing the theme, i kill the game, and then relaunch it, it works fine. which means the call from Appdelegate is fine, but i can't change the cache during run time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sprite frames reference textures. The textures are cached in CCTextureCache. You probably also need to remove the textures from the CCTextureCache.

And if you still have sprites on screen which are making use of texture A but you want them to make use of texture B, you have these options:

- send the setTexture: message with the new texture to each sprite
- remove the old sprites and add new ones
- reload the current scene

Note that calling `[CCSpriteFrameCache purgeSharedSpriteFrameCache];` is superfluous in any case. You don't need to deallocate the singleton, just purge whatever it is caching.

You can find a working solution for texture unloading and replacing the texture a sprite uses in the code for my [Cocos2D Webcam Viewer tutorial](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/01/download-modified-files-web-server-cocos2d-webcam-viewer/).

Comment: but different themes may use different stuff like in DefaultTheme, i don't have @"junglebg.png" in both texturecache and framecache, then after changing the theme, i want to use the FrameName which may or may not exist in DefaultTheme. (same frame name, but different set of files).

Comment: if i use spriteWithFile: @"junglebg.png" directly, which is of size 960x640, does it cost 1024x1024 memory? but if i use zwoptex, i need 2 1024x1024 sheets for other sprites, with a lot of empty space.